# jsonpath with kubectl to get "app.kuberentes.io/version" value

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath

I need to get the metadata->labels->app.kubernetes.io/version value from my pods.  But I can't seem to find the `jsonpath` that will allow the label key to have the slash and periods.

I have a basic command that is working:  `kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{end}" -A`.  This successfully returns name of each pods.

I have modified this to try to get the version.  Here are the permutations that I have attempted (each has failed):

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels.app.kubernetes.io/version}{end}" -A
```

and

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels.'app.kubernetes.io/version'}{end}" -A
```

and

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels.`"app.kubernetes.io`/version`"}{end}" -A
```

**How can I get the version using `jsonpath`?**

I am running in Windows PowerShell if that matters

Answer (score 7):

Escape dots in key name:

```
.metadata.labels.app\.kubernetes\.io/version
```

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels.app\.kubernetes\.io/version}{end}" -A
```